# how to read a php file and display in winform c#

Tags: c#, .net

How to read php file like http://toto/geri/xmloutput.php using c# winform?

What I only found is that we can use Xmlreader or dataset

Comment: Any normal file you can read using `File.ReadAllText("filename")`, how to display depends on need/requirement. I suggest post specific question and ask for help.

Comment: Your posted link doesnt work. Should it?

Comment: I think you just need to read the file, like Hari Prasad mentioned. Then use an extension to display the text (php code) with php syntax highlighting.

Comment: also, you should define "display" - Do you want an webpage output, or the actual code in the file as an output?